# How to create folders from text file in Python

Tags: python, file, parsing, directory

I'm a newbie in Python and trying to create folders in a hierarchy according to a text file.

for example, the text looks like this:

```
ant:ant:jar:1.5.1

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.10

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.3

com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.10
```

the folder needs to be created as follows:

```
ant\ant\1.5.1

com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-annotations\2.8.0

com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.7.3

com\fasterxml\jackson\core\jackson-core\2.8.10
```

part of the code to pars: (off.txt)

```
with open('off.txt') as f:

content = f.readlines()

for dependency in content:

slicedDependency = dependency.split(':')

var0 = slicedDependency[0]

if not var0.__contains__('.'):
    var1 = slicedDependency[1]
    var2 = slicedDependency[2]
    var4 = slicedDependency[3]

else:
    folderHirearchy = var0.split('.')

    if var0.__contains__('.'):

        for folder in folderHirearchy:
            print(folder)
```

parts of the code to write folders:

```
    # Set local variables
path = "path/offlineTest1"
main_folder_path = os.path.join(path)
main_foldNam1 = line.strip()
sub_folder1_path = os.path.join(main_folder_path, main_foldNam1)

# Create folder if it doesn't exist yet
if os.path.exists(sub_folder1_path):
    print("folder '{}' exists!".format(sub_folder1_path))
else:
    # create directory or directories until sub_folder1_path
    os.makedirs(sub_folder1_path)
```

Comment: who does define structure of the text file?

Comment: the structure of the text file is predefined  and use to create folders and zip them at the end

Comment: I manage to pars the simple part `ant:ant:jar:1.5.1` to groups, but the second one more complex  `com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.7.3` becous of the **:** and **.**

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions work wonders for cases like these

```
import re
import os

expr = re.compile(r"(?<!\d)[.:](?!\d+)")
with open("./off.txt", "r") as f:
  lines = f.readlines()
  """use a list comprehension and re.sub to replace dots and colons with slashes ("/"),
  and the "jar:"
  """
  folders = [
    expr.sub("/", line).replace("jar:","") for line in lines
    if len(line) > 1
  ]

for f in folders:
  print f
  os.makedirs(f)
```

Comment: thank you very much @RedSmoke, Regular expressions really work wonders for this case... :)
just now I notice that I had a typo error and at the beginning of the text I don't have ">" or extra whitespace

Comment: just need to delete the 1 from `line[1:]`

Comment: I revised the code example a bit. Now it just takes out the "jar:"

Comment: you are great, but you need to add `.strip()` 
`expr.sub("/", line.strip()).replace("jar:", "") for line in lines` .
I also notice in some edge cases that the regex is not cover like: "xpp3:xpp3_min:jar:1.1.4c" because we have digits(3) after xpp, so I change a bit to : `expr = re.compile(r"(?<!\W)[.:](?!\d+)")`